# How to include a script (variables, functions etc.) from another file for windows and linux?

Tags: function, variables, lua, include, require

First file named first.lua has:

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
var3 = 3

function first(var4)
print(var4)
return true
end
```

Second file named second.lua should have:

```
if var1 == 1 and var2 == 2 and var3 == 3 then
   first('goal')
end
```

How to include these variables and function on windows and linux? In PHP i use require or include a path file, but in lua? Thanks.

Comment: Did you do even a little bit of research before asking that question?

Comment: Start second file with line `require"first"`

Comment: and should i use a path like "folder/folder2/luafile" or "folder.folder2.luafile"? thanks

Comment: @WojciechGlapa - Use dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two files are in the same directory, the variables you want to access should be global OR returned

## First Way

FILE 1 named first.lua

```
      variable1 = "YOU CAN SEE ME !"
local variable2 = "YOU CANNOT !"
```

FILE 2 named second.lua

```
require("first") --> If file first.lua is in directory directName existing in the same area
                 --> as the file second.lua, use "directName/first"
                 --> if it's in the folder outside the current one, you can 
                 --> do ../first and so on it goes
print(variable1) --> This will print : YOU CAN SEE ME
print(variable2) --> This will print nil because variable2 does not exist in file2, it is local
```

## Second Way

Using this one, you can simply return a table at the end of the file

FILE 1 named first.lua

```
local to_access           = {} 
      to_access.variable1 = "HALLALOUJA"
local impossible_to_get   = "Hello"
return to_access               --> Note this return is very important
```

File 2 named second.lua

```
accessed = require("first")    --> or the path you use, without having .lua ofcourse
print    ( accessed.variable1 )--> This will print "HALLALOUJA"!
print    ( impossible_to_get  )--> Dear ol' nil will be printed
```